# iOS Dev: Segue by pressing a button in an Alert?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I've been searching for a few hours and haven't found any answers, so I would really appreciate your help!

I am designing an app and need to segue to a different view controller when a button in an alert is pressed.  I already have the alert set up, but just need the code to segue to a new view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. create alertview first.

```
UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message"  message:@"Open New controller?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
```

Implement the AlertView Delegate Method

```
#pragma mark AlertView Delegate
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
    {
        Viewcontroller *vc = [[UIViewcontroller alloc] initWithNib:@"Viewcontroller"];
        [self presentModalViewController:vc];
        [vc release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `UIAlertViewDelegate` and add the method `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`. Once the right button is clicked, call the method to segue into the new view.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `UIAlertViewDelegate` and then you get a callback with which button was pressed when the alert was dismissed.  Simply call `performSegueWithIdentifier` in there.

More details at the [UIAlertViewDelegate protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html)