# Segue after pressing a button in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uialertview, segue

I'm developing an app in which I need to show a `ViewController` when I press the "OK" button in an `UIAlertView`. How I can do that?

I found on here this solution: [iOS Dev: Segue by pressing a button in an Alert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957433/ios-dev-segue-by-pressing-a-button-in-an-alert), but it didn't work.

xCode says:

```
the method: presentModalViewController is deprecated
```

and I found on the web that I should use the method `presentViewController`.

I tried to do that but it shows me a black screen without any interaction, what's wrong?
I paste here my code, maybe you can help me.

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
    {
        PromoViewController *pvc = [[PromoViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: are  you using storyboard or not ?

Comment: See my answer :) it will do what you want with Storyboard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well another approach is to get the instance and do it programatically as

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                         bundle: nil];
PromoViewController *controller = (PromoViewController*)[mainStoryboard 
                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"<Controller ID>"];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Note controller ID is the storyboard id you set for the scene via attribute inspector

Comment: Yeah, it may work but you're completely missing the point of segues. ::Facepalm::

Comment: @Fogmeister : not completly missing the point.this is also right.I said in the answer explicitely, "Another approch" .If you miss that.And it is never wrong calling an instance

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a segue programatically you need to called `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

First make sure your segue has an identifier in the storyboard.

Then use this code instead...

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier"];
    }
}
```

This will do what you want.

Comment: I made so: 
1. In storyboard I connect the button with the new ViewController I've to load
2. In the code I inserted your solution
But when I press on the button I connected to the new ViewController it shows me the new ViewController first and then the UIAlertView

Answer (score 0):

See this: [Make button it UIAlertView perform Segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730481/make-button-it-uialertview-perform-segue)

It will show you how to create a manual segue and call it.